# Robot framework running Library command before Suite Setup?

Tags: python, robotframework

I've got a Suite Setup command that i would like to call before the Library command but RobotFramework seems to be calling the Library command before the Suite setup. I need it to be in chronological order because suite setup pulls down the libraries that the Library command is calling. I've got an extract from the robot file where it is messing up.

```
***Settings***

    Suite Setup   Call_Libraries ${GIT_Token}  # <---- Line called up 2nd
    Library    Hello.py <----- Line called up 1st
```

Apologies if my explanation isn't clear but i want the Suite Setup command to be called first and not the Library command. I am using robotframework 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Robotframework first loads the Library and Resources, and only the executes the Suite Setup.
There is nothing you can do about this.

What you can do, is to call the library import inside a step. Here is my example:

```
***Settings***
    Library    Hello.py # keep this import for RIDE to know keywords documentation (but can be removed after a first use, I think)
    Suite Setup   My Special Setup

*** Keywords ***
My Special Setup
    Call_Libraries ${GIT_Token}
    Import Library    Hello.py
```

Comment: if i do it that way, will the library be available globally or just available for that keyword?

Comment: I would expect for it to be available on Suite scope.